# In MUAI, using DXpopup and loading indicator in pagination

Tags: asynchronous, pagination, devexpress, maui, mobile-application

I tried several solutions, With Task.Run(()=>) it can be done.
UI froze when I try without Task, and it shows spinner only just before page change.
There is 2 example, first one is working, but not all pagination work is needed task. I want second one work, just like first one.

```
  Working one:
```

```
if (IsBusy) return;
       Platforms.KeyboardHelper.HideKeyboard();
       GlobalConstants.costantSpinner.Show();
       try
       {           
           GlobalVariables._loginDTO = await Task.Run(() => /*something to do before page change */);
           await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("somePage");
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {/* Display ex*/ }
       finally { IsBusy = false; GlobalConstants.costantSpinner.IsOpen = false; }
```

It works perfectly when with something to do before
Not working one:

```
  if (IsBusy) return;
            GlobalConstants.costantSpinner.Show();
            try { IsBusy = true; await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(/*Some page*/); }
            catch (Exception ex) {/* Display ex*/}
            finally { IsBusy = false; GlobalConstants.costantSpinner.IsOpen = false; }
```

Comment: I can't understand what you expect from the second one. You are showing a spinner and then you're immediately switching page, so the spinner doesn't have enough time to appear and rotate.

Comment: But there is time, when you try "GoToAsync" , code always wait for few seconds before navigate, because of the implamentation on next page such as loading something to show or some calculations to make. So You have a enough time to show indicator but in second one indicator does not show in first few seconds but shows in last second before pagination. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the spinner to appear and rotate for a while, you can add a delay before navigating to the other page.

```cs
if (IsBusy) return;
            GlobalConstants.costantSpinner.Show();
            
            try { IsBusy = true;
                  await Task.Delay(1000); // Add this line!
                  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(/*Some page*/); }
            catch (Exception ex) {/* Display ex*/}
            finally { IsBusy = false; GlobalConstants.costantSpinner.IsOpen = false; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I decrease delay to 500, and it worked like a charm!